# Is there a way to add a Mapbox style to Drupal Leaflet?

Tags: views

I have recently upgraded to the latest version of Drupal, and the module 'Leaflet Mapbox' (https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet_mapbox) is no longer supported.  I was wondering how I would go about adding a Mapbox style to the Drupal Leaflet map?  I have tried following the Mapbox documentation, however, the leaflet map is already a container on drupal so this does not work.

Comment: Which version of Drupal, specifically? If you upgraded from 7 to 8, there is a dev version of the module here: https://www.drupal.org/project/contrib_tracker/issues/2756323  You can install that, but since it is a dev release it may have broken features and/or bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The Leaflet Mapbox module has now been released for Drupal 8/9